# Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix in ADT xml editor

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout      
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:padding="10px"
    android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true">
```

The error "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix" is reported at the last line: android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last attribute is invalid.
attributes need to begin with `android:` which is known as the namespace.

It looks like you're trying to use the java method inside the xml which will not work.
I think the attribute you're looking for is `android:scrollbar` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true"
```

with this

```
 android:setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

Because xmlns:tools declaration is missing. The code should look like this:

```
<RelativeLayout      
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:padding="10px"
    android:setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true">
```

Comment: Thanks. What if the namespace     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" has been defined in the parent element: ScrollView, like this: <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android".
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <RelativeLayout
...
  android.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled="true">, then I got an error: "Unexpected namespace prefix xmlns..."

Comment: xmlns will define a namespace for use in the xml. In the question above, the code does not use the `tools` namespace.